# Как изменить цвет выбранной вкладки QTabWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qtabwidget

Как обратиться к шапке вкладки и покрасить именно её одну вкладку?

Есть два варианта которые меня не устраивают.

**`Первый`** когда меняется цвет всех вкладок.

```
self.tabs = self.tabWidget.tabBar()
self.tabs.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255,255,0);")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**`Второй`** метод когда меняется цвет всей вкладки.

```
#self.tabs = self.tabWidget.tabBar()
self.tab_sau_tka_1.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255,255,0);")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Создал пример с данной проблемой:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(297, 175)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 241, 101))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 297, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


        # вот тут пытаюсь обратится по первому способу ко вкладкам
        self.for_color_tabs = self.tabWidget.tabBar()
        self.for_color_tabs.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255,255,0);")
        # тут обращаюсь по второму способу ко вкладке
        self.tab_2.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255,255,0);")


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Страница"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

То, что хотел на данный момент, не получается через `QTabWidget`. 
Сделал через `QStackWidget` с помощью кнопок. Выглядит громоздко и наверное это костыль...

Надеюсь кто-то сможет мне объяснить и показать как это сделать правильно или найдет такого человека.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(406, 255)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 381, 181))
        self.stackedWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);")
        self.stackedWidget.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.stackedWidget.setLineWidth(0)
        self.stackedWidget.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 71, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_new_color_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
        self.pushButton_new_color_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 211, 23))
        self.pushButton_new_color_1.setObjectName("pushButton_new_color_1")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 71, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_new_color_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.pushButton_new_color_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 90, 211, 23))
        self.pushButton_new_color_2.setObjectName("pushButton_new_color_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_3)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 71, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton_new_color_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page_3)
        self.pushButton_new_color_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 211, 23))
        self.pushButton_new_color_3.setObjectName("pushButton_new_color_3")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        self.pushButton_tab1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_tab1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 75, 31))
        self.pushButton_tab1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);border: 1px solid #C4C4C3; border-bottom #C4C4C3")
        self.pushButton_tab1.setObjectName("pushButton_tab1")
        self.pushButton_tab2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_tab2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 0, 75, 31))
        self.pushButton_tab2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);border: 1px solid #C4C4C3")
        self.pushButton_tab2.setObjectName("pushButton_tab2")
        self.pushButton_tab3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_tab3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 0, 75, 31))
        self.pushButton_tab3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);border: 1px solid #C4C4C3")
        self.pushButton_tab3.setObjectName("pushButton_tab3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 406, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
        # переменная для контроля аварии и задания красного цвета для вкладок
        self.alarm_tab1 = False
        self.alarm_tab2 = False
        self.alarm_tab3 = False
        # ниже переменные с описанием стиле qss для изменния отображения кнопок от их состояния
        self.enable_button = "background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);border: 1px solid #C4C4C3; border-bottom #C4C4C3"
        self.disable_button = "background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);border: 1px solid #C4C4C3"
        self.alarm_enable_button = "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);border: 1px solid #C4C4C3; border-bottom #C4C4C3"
        self.alarm_disable_button = "background-color: rgb(200, 0, 0);border: 1px solid #C4C4C3"
        # ниже присваиваем нажатию кнопок методы которые выводят необходимые вкладки QStackWidget и меняем qss кнопки
        self.pushButton_tab1.clicked.connect(self.tab1_show)
        self.pushButton_tab2.clicked.connect(self.tab2_show)
        self.pushButton_tab3.clicked.connect(self.tab3_show)
        self.pushButton_new_color_1.clicked.connect(self.new_color_2)
        self.pushButton_new_color_2.clicked.connect(self.new_color_3)
        self.pushButton_new_color_3.clicked.connect(self.new_color_1)
        # кнопка показывает страницу QStackWidget, изменяет свой qss на активный, остальные кнопки на неактивный
        # если есть условие аварии то цвета другие, но тоже активные и не актиные кнопки взводятся 
    def tab1_show(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.pushButton_tab1.setStyleSheet(self.enable_button)
        self.pushButton_tab2.setStyleSheet(self.disable_button)
        self.pushButton_tab3.setStyleSheet(self.disable_button)
        if self.alarm_tab1:
            self.pushButton_tab1.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_enable_button)
        if self.alarm_tab2:
            self.pushButton_tab2.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_disable_button)
        if self.alarm_tab3:
            self.pushButton_tab3.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_disable_button)

    def tab2_show(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.pushButton_tab2.setStyleSheet(self.enable_button)
        self.pushButton_tab1.setStyleSheet(self.disable_button)
        self.pushButton_tab3.setStyleSheet(self.disable_button)
        if self.alarm_tab2:
            self.pushButton_tab2.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_enable_button)
        if self.alarm_tab1:
            self.pushButton_tab1.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_disable_button)
        if self.alarm_tab3:
            self.pushButton_tab3.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_disable_button)

    def tab3_show(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.pushButton_tab3.setStyleSheet(self.enable_button)
        self.pushButton_tab1.setStyleSheet(self.disable_button)
        self.pushButton_tab2.setStyleSheet(self.disable_button)
        if self.alarm_tab3:
            self.pushButton_tab3.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_enable_button)
        if self.alarm_tab1:
            self.pushButton_tab1.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_disable_button)
        if self.alarm_tab2:
            self.pushButton_tab2.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_disable_button)

    # вызываем аварию для изменения цвета и если она есть то снимаем от повторного нажатия
    def new_color_2(self):
        if self.alarm_tab2:
            self.alarm_tab2 = False
            self.pushButton_tab2.setStyleSheet(self.disable_button)
            return
        self.pushButton_tab2.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_disable_button)
        self.alarm_tab2 = True

    def new_color_3(self):
        if self.alarm_tab3:
            self.alarm_tab3 = False
            self.pushButton_tab3.setStyleSheet(self.disable_button)
            return
        self.pushButton_tab3.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_disable_button)
        self.alarm_tab3 = True

    def new_color_1(self):
        if self.alarm_tab1:
            self.alarm_tab1 = False
            self.pushButton_tab1.setStyleSheet(self.disable_button)
            return
        self.pushButton_tab1.setStyleSheet(self.alarm_disable_button)
        self.alarm_tab1 = True

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TAB 1"))
        self.pushButton_new_color_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Условие для изменения цвета"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TAB 2"))
        self.pushButton_new_color_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Условие для изменения цвета"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TAB 3"))
        self.pushButton_new_color_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Условие для изменения цвета"))
        self.pushButton_tab1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.pushButton_tab2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))
        self.pushButton_tab3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tab 3"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, тогда так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 475)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
#        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 241, 201))
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 400))
        
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
# +++        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button", self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit("TextEdit", self.tab)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label", self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label 2", self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("LineEdit", self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
# +++       
        
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 297, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Страница"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # вот тут пытаюсь обратится по первому способу ко вкладкам
#        self.for_color_tabs = self.tabWidget.tabBar()
#        self.for_color_tabs.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0);")
        # тут обращаюсь по второму способу ко вкладке
#        self.tab.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255,255,0);") 


qss = """ 
QTabBar::tab:selected  {
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0);
}  
QTabBar::tab:!selected {
    background-color:rgb(220, 220, 220); 
}
""" 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Windows')
#    app.setStyle('Fusion')               # попробуйте

    app.setStyleSheet(qss)

    w = MainWindow()
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    app.setStyle('Windows')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понятно выразился я. Нужно чтобы цвет вкладки менялся не от активности,  а когда мое условие скажет что нужно менять цвет и это привлечет пользователя. Мне само обращение к заголовку вкладки интересует. Вижу QTabBar::tab:selected. Где можно посмотреть команды просто на статический постоянный цвет, чтобы вызвать его изменение по условию? это какой то CSS для QT или общепринятый? не разбираюсь в стилях CSS(   да и в программировании

Comment: Просмотрел источники официальные и не нашел как обратится именно к  определенной шапке вкладки https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#previous-selected-ps . На других форумах с ответами не нашел, есть только обращение ко вкладке через QWidget#Name_tab{...}
, но это закрашивает саму вкладку так как я обращаюсь к ней, а не шапку QTabBar ((( Похоже это не реализуемо данным подходом, или не учел что то.

Comment: Добавил вариант с реализацией через QStackedWidget , видимо придется идти через костыль. Может мой вопрос кому то и поможет, т.к. кнопки и QStackedWidget можно изменять как угодно. Буду рад увидеть или услышать другие более оптимальные идеи по реализации данного вопроса.